# Positive synonym for 'exploit'

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I want to know a single word which denotes the idea of full or maximum utilization, such as the words *exploit* or *milk*. But the trouble is, they both have a negative tone to them. Is there a positive word which can be substituted for 'best use' etc.

Comment: Now that I think about it, optimal seems like a pretty good choice. Like he made optimal use of the opportunity. Has a definite positive ring to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it's worth pointing out that ***exploit*** doesn't always have a negative connotation, particularly in the context of *exploit the benefits of...* (or, *exploit the advantages of...*)

> *"Hardware support alone is not sufficient to* exploit *the benefits of multithreading. We believe that the performance benefits of
>   multithreading can only be realized when the paradigm is applied
>   across all levels..."* (M. Zelkowitz)

Most online dictionaries I consulted showed two definitions - one positive, and one negative.  Moreover, the positive sense of the word was usually listed first.  From Merriam-Webster's:

> **exploit** (*trans. verb*) 1 : to make productive use of; to utilize   2 : to
>   make use of meanly or unfairly for one's own advantage

Nonetheless, the negative connotation is undeniably there.  If you're looking for a synonym without that negative connotation, you might try ***leverage*** (already suggested) or ***harness***.

Answer (score 4):

I’m not up-to-date with the latest trends in business jargon, but I know that *leverage* supplanted *utilize* as the favoured term for “get the most from”.  *Optimize* also has some currency.

As you say, exploiting people is not OK, but business jargon gets around this by either dehumanizing (are humans really just annother “resource”?) or recasting in a positive light.

> Here at MegaCorp, every individual counts.  We strive for excellence in all things, and we work with our team members to help them reach their maximum potential and achieve their career goals.

In other words:

> Here at MegaCorp, there is no room for slackers.  Only the strong survive, and you’re going to have to give us everything you’ve got if you want to get on here.

Answer (score 3):

What about 'capitalize on'? To my my American ear it does not sound negative, but maybe it isn't 'correct'.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *[maximize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maximize)*:

> : to make the most of

Comment: Yes. True. But to be honest, the word maximize has so much been used with the word profit, that it feels like it has a corporate air to it. I mean, semantically speaking it's just the word. But is there any other?

Comment: [_Leverage_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/leverage) is popular these days.

Comment: Ever since Jack Sparrow mentioned leverage?

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish, there **is** such a verb: *aprovechar*. But there doesn't seem to be any single English word that captures all of that, without also being prone to pejorative use.

Several phrases, like *take advantage of*, *utilize* (or *use*) *efficiently*, and so on, present themselves, but in the end they are always about efficiency of manipulating or producing objects, not about people. So there's no way to get rid of the pejorative impulses that surround these terms; they're unavoidable whenever more than one person is involved in the resource being efficiently used or the advantage being taken.

Comment: An 8k person saying this, discourages me. But I would still wait for someone to answer before I accept any :)

Answer (score 0):

For a more positive connotation that doesn't sound too "corporate" you might try synonyms from the agricultural realm such as: ***harvest*** or ***cultivate***.